# asp.net Response.WriteFile not working with Azure App Proxy?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, proxy

I've written an on-premise web app that allows the user to download a file from the backend server, using `Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)`

This works perfectly, when I access the on-premise web app directly.

However, when I try to access the web app remotely via the Azure App Proxy, the download fails (no useful error codes).

I've configured custom domains, and both the internal and external URL of the web app are identical.
Everything works fine with the App Proxy, including uploading files to the backend server.

It is only downloads using `Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)` which fail.
If I tried to download using http://URL/pathtofile, it works, but it doesn't fit my workflow.

Does anyone know how to get `Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)` working with the Azure App Proxy in between?

Answer (score 0):

To get work with Azure App Proxy,
**instead of  `Response.WriteFile()` Use  `Response.TransmitFile()`**

Here is the way i am able to download file in Azure App Service

**Step-1:**
**Replace your code with `Response.TransmitFile()`  **

My Code:

```cs
    protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/your file path"); // Update with your file path

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));

            // Transmit the file to the client
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);

            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("File not found or an error occurred.");
        }
    }
```

**Step-2:Deploy to Azure App**

**Click Download button**
[image]

[image]